# mod_rewrite not working with my simple url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The problem is that I cannot make my URL change with the mod_rewrite, the URL I have is this:

```
http://example.org/files/news.php?news=180
```

I wish to see something like this:

```
http://example.org/files/news/180
```

I've tried these code (every single commented RewriteRule):

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
# RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.org/notfound.php

Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /files/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/ news.php?news=$1
#RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+) /news?news=$1
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/ files/news.php?news=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ news.php?news=$1 [L]
```

And nothing, How do the code should look like?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in `/files/.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.org/notfound.php

Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /files/

RewriteRule ^news/([^/.]+)/?$ news.php?news=$1 [L,QSA]
```